# How to access a token instance created by another smart contract constructor

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, tokens

I am using a smart contract which creates a token instance in its constructor:

```
contract Exemple{

       Token public myToken

       function Exemple(){
               myToken=Token(this);
       }
}
```

How can i access this token instance from outside of the contract (using truffle console)? For instance to make a command such as: `myToken.approve(address,value, {from: other_account})`

Hope my question makes sense. Just a beginner here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get contract instance as below:

Using Web3:

```
    // ------- Get Web3 instance --------------------------------------------------------------
    var web3Client = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

    // ------- Get ABI of the contract ---------------------------------------------------------
    // #################### REPLACE it with your ABI #############################
    var myContractABI = <contract ABI>;

    // ------- Get address of the contract -----------------------------------------------------
    // #################### REPLACE it with your Address #############################
    var myContractAddress = '<address of the contract from which it is deployed>';

    // ------- Create contract client ----------------------------------------------------------
    var myContract = web3Client.eth.contract(myContractABI);

    // ------- Create contract instance --------------------------------------------------------
    var myContractInstance = myContract.at(myContractAddress);

    // ------- Invoke any method of the instance ------------------------------------------------
    myContractInstance.myContractMethod();
```

From Truffle console:

```
    myContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        myContractInstance = instance;
    })

    myContractInstance.myMethod()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is how your contract looks:

```
contract Example {

   Token public myToken;

   //constructor  
  function Example() {
       myToken = new Token();
  }
}
contract Token {
   function getInt() constant returns(uint) {
       return 1;
   }
}
```

Then you need first to get object of your example smart contract. Code below is using web3js, in truffle things are a bit simpler, since contract **calls** and **transactions** returns a promise, so there is no need to provide callbacks and you may use `then()` function.:

```
var exampleContractInstance = web3.eth.contract(abiArray).at(contractAddress);
```

Then you need to get reference to your Token instance address with:

```
exampleContractInstance.myToken.call(function(error, addressOfToken) {});
```

Be aware that this function will not return you a smart contract object. It will return address, where your smart contract is e.g. `0xd21b9493802cf961e96efcde89958093d0172b76`.
Then you need to get object for your Token instance using addressOfToken:

```
var tokenContractInstance = web3.eth.contract(abiArray).at(addressOfToken);
```

Now you have object representing your Token instance and you may interact with it e.g.

```
tokenContractInstance.getInt.call(function(error, integerValue) {});
```

**PS 1** Ouside of truffle console or truffle test, you will need **abiArray** to interact with your contracts. It should be provided by your IDE (e.g. https://remix.ethereum.org). In truffle console you may skip it since your contract definition is already there (reference here http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/console):

```
Example.at(addressOfContract)
```

**PS 2** Be aware that return values would be inside callbacks, so don't expect that call function will return you value **returned** by the contract.